# Activex component can't create object:'xyz'

Tags: vbscript, activex

I have written the following piece of VB script which opens
an existing aplication `xyz` from the path I specfied.
The application (a custom windows application) opens succesfully.
(I would like to use the automation interface of this application
in my vb script.) for that I call `CreateObject`.

But, then I also get the error `Activex component can't create object: 'xyz'` for the line `Set xyzObj = CreateObject("xyz")`.
The error is from this line, since if I remove this line there is no error.

```
Dim objShell 

Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
objShell.Exec("C:\abc\def\xyz.exe") 

Set xyzObj = CreateObject("xyz")

Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CreateObject like that with a external program, started in your script or otherwise. CreateObject loads a COM-object that is registered on your pc. Google on vbscript and COM objects and you'll find plenty of info like at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156598.aspx. If you want to interact with a started program you could use the sendkeys method or better use the autoit com object , see http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/ComRef.htm